# Passing of variable from php to shell script

Tags: php, expect, shell-exec

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
$var1="hello.txt";
exec("expect /home/foo.sh $var1");
?>
```

and my shell script:

```
spawn su -s /bin/bash root -c "/usr/bin/gpg --output /home/$1.gpg --encrypt --recipient sampleonly@yahoo.com  /home/$1"
expect "Password:"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "*complete*"
```

It doesn't get my variable

Comment: Have you tried with `exec("expect /home/foo.sh " . $var1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your arguments to variables like this:

Shell Script:

```
set name [lrange $argv 0 0]
send -- "Hello $name"
```

Terminal command:

```
expect hello.sh Benjamin
```

Result:

```
Hello Benjamin
```

Comment: I used set var1 [lindex $argv 0] but it stacks it value

Comment: What's the difference between lrange and lindex?

Comment: `[lrange $argv 0 0]` is equivalent to `[lindex $argv 0]`

Comment: so it doesn't matter what to use? :D